# How to load a video by selecting it from a dropdown list in a asp.net webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a dropdown list that contains a list of videos names without file extension.  I also have an embedded HTML5 video player.  Currently the video player is hard-coded with a video found in the Uploads folder.  I want to pass the video name from the dropdown list to video player so it loads the selected video.  Each video has three supported formats (mp4, ogv and webm).  I just want to pass the video name without the file extension to each of the 3 video formats.  The video that is loaded will depend on what the user browser supports with Mp4 being tried first then ogv and finally webm .  I also have a script that will load an .flv video if the main 3 formats are not supported by the user browser.

Thank you ahead of time for any assistance you may give.

Here is my code for the dropdown list and video player:

```
<div>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" EntityTypeName="">
  </asp:LinqDataSource>
</div>
<div id='media-player'>
  <video id='media-video' controls>
    <source src="Uploads/Changing Master Key.Mp4" type='video/Mp4'>
    <source src="Uploads/Changing Master Key.webm" type='video/webm'>
    <source src="Uploads/Changing Master Key.ogv" type='video/ogv'>
  </video>
</div>
```

Here is my code behind for the dropdown list:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"));

      Dictionary<string, string> filenames = new Dictionary<string, string>();

      foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
      {
        var file_name_without_extension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);

        if (filenames.ContainsKey(file_name_without_extension))
          continue;

        filenames.Add(file_name_without_extension, filePath);
      }

      List<ListItem> files = filenames.Select(x => new ListItem(x.Key, x.Value)).ToList();

      DropDownList1.DataSource = files;
      DropDownList1.DataTextField = "";
      DropDownList1.DataValueField = "";
      DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
  }
```

I have updated my code based on Khazratbek suggestion below.

```
  protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string YourFilePathWithFileName = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    media_video.Attributes.Add("src", "/Uploads/" + YourFilePathWithFileName + ".mp4");
    media_video.Attributes.Add("type", "video/mp4");
    media_video.Attributes.Add("autoplay", "autoplay");
    media_video.Attributes.Add("src", "/Uploads/" + YourFilePathWithFileName + ".ogv");
    media_video.Attributes.Add("type", "video/ogv");
    media_video.Attributes.Add("autoplay", "autoplay");
    media_video.Attributes.Add("src", "/Uploads/" + YourFilePathWithFileName + ".webm");
    media_video.Attributes.Add("type", "video/webm");
    media_video.Attributes.Add("autoplay", "autoplay");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may approach one way.

```
<div>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" EntityTypeName="">
  </asp:LinqDataSource>
</div>
<div id="media-player">
  <video id="media_video" runat="server" controls>
  </video>
</div>
```

And your SelectedIndexChanged method:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    media_video.Attributes.Add("src", YourFilePathWithFileName);
    media_video.Attributes.Add("type", "video/mp4");
    media_video.Attributes.Add("autoplay", "autoplay");
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to inject the file name into the video player on change event of the dropdown

Create a webmethod that will pass the filename on change event of the dropdown. Call the webmethod as an jquery ajax call and get the file name and inject it in the video player control